# Using conditional expression in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, conditional-statements

I got the following error, isn't it possible to use this expression in my JSP?

```
value="${ user.niveauuser == 0 ? 'banni' : ${ user.niveauuser == 2 ? 'membre' : ${ user.niveauuser == 3 ? 'modérateur' : 'Administrateur'}}}" /></td>
```

What's wrong with this expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it removing the nested `${ }`:

```
value="${ user.niveauuser == 0 ? 'banni' : 
    user.niveauuser == 2 ? 'membre' : 
        user.niveauuser == 3 ? 'modérateur' : 'Administrateur'}"
```

Comment: Thank you trogdor, can you suggest me a good topic about webapps for more practice please ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
<c:set var="usertype" value=""/>

<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${user.niveauuser == 0}">
      <c:set var="usertype" value="banni"/>
   </c:when>
   <c:when test="${user.niveauuser == 2}">
      <c:set var="usertype" value="membre"/>
   </c:when>
   <c:when test="${user.niveauuser == 3}">
      <c:set var="usertype" value="modérateur"/>
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
      <c:set var="usertype" value="Administrateur"/>
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<c:out value="${usertype}"/>
```

or better to implement this logic in backend.

Comment: thank you Alex, can you suggest me a good topic about webapps for more practice please ?

Comment: @meee meeee Search "spring petclinic" (but this uses spring as well). You can find it in github.